# Optimizing subquery in sql

Tags: sql

Given the following SQL query

```
SELECT * 
FROM geotypes 
WHERE geotype_id IN (SELECT geotype_id 
                     FROM geotype_mixed 
                     WHERE test_name = $1) 
ORDER BY latest_date DESC 
LIMIT 100
```

Recently this query has been taking longer to execute and as I am new to SQL I am wondering if there is anyway to optimize it further? I feel I may not have the most optimal query.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Do you have indexes on geotype_mixed.test_name and geotypes.geotype_id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general subqueries does not perform well. Also, "IN" operator also not good when looking for performance. So, I would try changing your query as below:

```
SELECT * FROM geotypes gt
join geotype_mixed gtm on gt.geotype_id = gtm.geotype_id
WHERE gtm.test_name = $1
ORDER BY latest_date DESC LIMIT 100
```

since test_name is used in filtering, creating index on text_name will help improving the performance. Also, index on latest_date (but usually indexes on datetime column won't make big difference but okay to consider. if its just date column then yes, you will see some improvement). I am assuming geotype_id would be primary key and/or foreign keys in respective tables. If that is not the case, you will need indexes on them as well.

Comment: "*In general subqueries do not perform well*"  is simply not true. And rewriting an `IN` condition to a JOIN changes the meaning of the query

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend writing the query using `exists` and then using indexes:

```
SELECT g.*
FROM geotypes g
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
              FROM geotype_mixed gm
              WHERE gm.geotype_id = g.geotype_id AND
                    gm.test_name = $1
             ) 
ORDER BY latest_date DESC
LIMIT 100;
```

The two indexes are:

- `geotype_mixed(geotype_id, test_name)`
- `geotypes(latest_date desc, geotype_id)`